# PHP getAttribute('value') from childNodes

Tags: php

I have a form that contains multiple Select
I want to retrieve the `getAttribute('value')` and `textContent` of the `<option>` elements
to build an array

**I have a code that works under:**
PHP Versions 5.6.34, 7.2.34, 7.4.21

**Does not work under:**
PHP Versions 7.0.33, 7.4.33

Example of my code:

```html
</form>
<select id="imageextention" name="imageextention" onchange="viewimage('formsig');" class="select">
<option value="blue.gif">sigblue</option>
<option value="green.gif">siggreen</option>
<option value="orange.gif">sigorange</option>
</select>

<select id="fontcolor" name="fontcolor" onchange="viewimage('formsig');">
<option value="#7BCEDE">blue</option>
<option value="#A5B531">green</option>
<option value="#FF8C29">orange</option>
<option value="#F76B7B">pink</option>
<option value="#B584BD">purple</option>
<option value="#FFBD08">yellow</option>
</select>
</form>
```

```php
   $tagname = $doc->getElementById('imageextention')->nodeName;
   if ($tagname == "select") {
      $serials = $doc->getElementById('imageextention')->childNodes;
      $imageextentionM = array();
      foreach ($serials as $n) {
           array_push($imageextentionM[$n->getAttribute('value')] = $n->textContent);
      }
   }

   $tagname2 = $doc->getElementById('fontcolor')->nodeName;
   if ($tagname2 == "select") {
      $serials = $doc->getElementById('fontcolor')->childNodes;
      $fontcolorM = array();
      foreach ($serials as $n) {
         array_push($fontcolorM[$n->getAttribute('value')] = $n->textContent);
      }
      $activecolortxtM="";
   }
}
```

with PHP Versions 7.0.33, 7.4.33 I have this error:

> Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute() ...... Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ....

It does not recognize `getAttribute('value')` for child elements

I know my code is not clean.

I tried with `getElementsByTagName` but it lists me all "option" elements of the page

```php
$num = $doc->getElementById("imageextention")->childNodes->length;
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('option');
for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
   $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('option');
   $imageextentionM[$items[$i]->getAttribute('value')]= $items[$i]->textContent;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: _"I tried with getElementsByTagName but it lists me all "option" elements of the page"_ - that method does not only exist on document, it exists on each element as well. So you can simply call `$doc->getElementById("imageextention")->getElementsByTagName('option')`, and it will only get you the options of that specific select element.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but you expect somewhere to get the DOMElement object but you get DOMText object instead (or in addition) which do not have method getAttribute, most likely at `->childNodes` which also contains the text nodes. So check for the type would solve the error:

```
foreach ($serials as $n) {
    if($n instanceof \DOMElement){
        array_push($imageextentionM[$n->getAttribute('value')] = $n->textContent);
    }
    // to investigate which object you got instead:
    /* else { 
        var_dump($n);
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great !
It works, thank you very much  @CBore

My code :

```
  $tagname2 = $doc->getElementById('fontcolor')->nodeName;
  if ($tagname2 == "select") {
     $serials = $doc->getElementById("imageextention")->getElementsByTagName('option');
     $fontcolorM = array();
     foreach ($serials as $n) {
        array_push($fontcolorM[$n->getAttribute('value')] = $n->textContent);
     }
     $activecolortxtM="";
  }
}
```